# r piping image_annotate doesn't work as expected

Tags: r, imagemagick, animated-gif, purrr, piping

I am trying to using `magick` to create an animated gif from a bunch of images. It works just fine but I wanted to annotate text (basically the file name) to each image before creating the gif - and that doesn't work.

I can't find the cause of the error (below) - not sure if it is the piping notation, the map function, or something else.

```
library(purrr)
library(magick)

#set working directory with a couple of png's
#This works:
image_read("image1.png") %>% image_annotate("Text")    

#and this works too:
list.files(path = "", pattern = "*.png", full.names = T) %>% 
      map(image_read) %>%
      image_join() %>% 
      image_animate(fps=1) %>% 
      image_write("animated.gif")

#but this doesn't:
list.files(path = "", pattern = "*.png", full.names = T) %>% 
      map(image_read) %>%
      map(image_annotate("Text")) %>%
      image_join() %>% 
      image_animate(fps=1) %>% 
      image_write("animated.gif")
```

I get this error:
`Error in inherits(image, "magick-image") : 
  argument "image" is missing, with no default`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as though the error might be in nesting your map.

Since you have already mapped during `image_read`, it is not necessary to do so again for `image_annotate`,

**Edit**
So we need to apply the function `image_annotate` to each element in the list returned by the mapped `image_read`. Try replacing `map(image_annotate("Text") %>%` with :

```
lapply(image_annotate("Text")) %>%
```

or

```
lapply(. %>% image_annotate("Text")) %>%
```

[Reference for lapply()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/lapply)

Comment: I thought so - but I got the error:
`Error: The 'image' argument is not a magick image object.`

Comment: aah yes i missed a step, have edited my answer, let me know if it works :)

Comment: Thanks - the first didn't work but the second did the job!
Is there a way to annotate the filename instead of "Text"?

Comment: Yes, any string variable will work. For example you could store each filename to a string and use that.

Comment: sure thing but how do I get the filename within this dplyr chain to use in as text?

Comment: something along the lines of `mapply(image_annotate(list.files(path = "", pattern = "*.png", full.names = T))) %>%` might work... im not too sure

Comment: It probably deserves a larger seperate answer as its not exactly related to the original question. Perhaps post another question?

Comment: Fair enough. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46923970/r-dplyr-read-list-of-files-and-use-filename-as-a-variable