# r dplyr - read list of files and use filename as a variable

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I would like to replace the "Text" below in image_annotate by the name of each file.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(magick)

list.files(path = "", pattern = "*.png", full.names = T) %>% 
      map(image_read) %>%
      lapply(. %>% image_annotate("Text")) %>%
      image_join() %>% 
      image_animate(fps=1) %>% 
      image_write("animated.gif")
```

Comment: @Mako212 wouldn't this just pass the image to image_annotate without the information about the name? Or is it stored somewhere in that object? I think both should be done within the first `map` to share the filename-information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this should work. Since you get the information about the filename and pass it to the `image_read` but want to use this information also for another function (`image_annotate`), you can easily put the two in a function within `map`. If you don't want the whole path as annotation, just replace `image_annotate(fnme)` by `image_annotate(stringr::str_extract(string = fnme, pattern = "(?<=(/|\\\\)).+(?=\\.png)"))` which matches anything between `/` or `\` and `.png` (assuming that you don't want the ending, else just remove the lookahead `(?=\\.png`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(magick)

list.files(path = "", pattern = "*.png", full.names = T) %>% 
      map(function(fnme) {
          image_read(fnme) %>% image_annotate(fnme)
      }) %>%
      image_join() %>% 
      image_animate(fps=1) %>% 
      image_write("animated.gif")
```

Comment: You can use `file_path_sans_ext` packaged with `base` to avoid the acrobatics of *regex* here

Comment: I do like the concise use of the anonymous function here. Just be wary of the missing closing curly brace. Otherwise, entirely functional.

Comment: @KevinArseneau thanks for that `file_path_sans_text`, I was not aware of that function :) However, this doesn't cut away the path but only the extension and you have to do `full.names = FALSE`, as in your solution. But in the question it explicitly says `full.names = FALSE`. Fixed the missing } as well.

Comment: that's true, but when you run `list.files(full.names = FALSE)` then you get only the file name without extention

Answer (score 3):

The `lapply` won't work in your piped chain because `image_annotate` won't accept more than one value. You can use a vector of the names and `map2` from `purrr`.

```
path <- ""
pattern <- "*.png"    

file_name <- list.files(path, pattern, full.names = FALSE) %>%
  tools::file_path_sans_ext()

list.files(path, pattern, full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  map(image_read) %>%
  map2(file_name, image_annotate) %>%
  image_join() %>% 
  image_animate(fps = 1) %>% 
  image_write("animated.gif")
```

#### Edit

If you prefer the full path file names included in the `image_annotate`, you could forego the vector assignment preceding the pipe and add an `assign` inline.

```
list.files(path, pattern, full.names = T) %>%
  assign("file_name", value = ., pos = 1) %>%
  map(image_read) %>%
  map2(file_name, image_annotate) %>%
  image_join() %>% 
  image_animate(fps = 1) %>% 
  image_write("animated.gif")
```