# Piping image_annotate with string array

Tags: r, for-loop, pipe, imagemagick

I am trying to annotate an image with a loop using pipe operators in magick to replace this code:

```
Strings <- c('Some text', 'Some other text')
Locations <- c("+10+10", "+30+50")

image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/frink.png") %>%
  image_annotate(Strings[1], location = Locations[1], size = 20)  %>%
  image_annotate(Strings[2], location = Locations[2], size = 20)
```

Based on this [r piping image_annotate doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921733/r-piping-image-annotate-doesnt-work-as-expected) , I tried

```
image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/frink.png") %>%
  lapply(image_annotate(Strings, location = Locations, size = 20))
```

This results in `Error: The 'image' argument is not a magick image object.`. And

```
  lapply(. %>% image_annotate(Strings, location = Locations, size = 20))
```

That gives the error `Error in magick_image_annotate(image, text, gravity, location, degrees,  :  Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=2].`

What would be the correct way of writing it?